# ArangoDB Quick api to know if 2 document keys has edges b/w them

Tags: arangodb

If I have 2 vertices V1 and V2. Which method gives me the direct edge array b/w these 2 vertices.

### Collection c

V1 = {"name": "a"} 
V2 = {"name": "b"}

### Edges e

E1 = (V1, V2, {"count": 1})

Now, I am adding V2 again (ie. it has the same key). First, I want to get E1 quickly. Ideally I was thinking if we have in Arangodb something like

`edgeList = db.e.edges(v1, v2);`

It should return the edges array b/w v1 and v2.

I was looking for the best practice for this db.e.edges

After addition of V2 again the E1 will look like :
`E1 = (V1, V2, {"count" : 2})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following AQL methods to solve this:

1. GRAPH_SHORTEST_PATH

   RETURN GRAPH_SHORTEST_PATH("yourGraph", "V1_ID", "V2_ID", {direction : "any"})

This Will return the shortes path between those edges, if the length is 1 there is direct edge  between V1 and V2

2. GRAPH_EDGES

RETURN GRAPH_EDGES("yourGraph", "V1_ID", {maxDepth : 1, direction : "any"})

This will return all incoming and outgoing edges for a maximal depth of 1 for V1, just filter the result for V2

Comment: I am new to Arangodb and have not made progress to Graph, so I hace no graph as such. I have 2 collection 'm' as document and 'e' as edge. While adding a new document to m I am searching if the edge needs to be updated or created. 
I am using this approach:
[code]  
  v2 = //my new doc
  docs = db.metrics.range("time", timeStart, docTime);
  while(docs.hasNext()) {
 v1 = docs.next();
 db.link.outEdges(v1).forEach(function(edge) {

 newedge = null;
 if(edge._to == v2._id) {
 print('Edge needs to be updated');
 createRequired = false;
 newedge = edge;
 return; 
 }
});
  }
[/code]

Comment: I guess the best practice is to create the graph first and then do the traversing over it instead of the way I am doing ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to us relations (edges) between vertices you definitely want to use the graph module:

Answer (score 0):

I am still no sure what your aiming to do. Note that when you create a new vertex (in your example V2) the vertex id is newly created and hence not in any already existing edge. 
Please describe what exactly you want to do and i will try to give you a best practice example

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i checked this and for the time being you have to call an AQL to check for existing edges between 2 vertices :

```
db._query("FOR i in GRAPH_EDGES("yourGraphName",v1,{neighborExamples : v2}) RETURN i").toArray();
```

We will offer a more convenient method in 2.3.1 soon, it will be in the graph module and can be used like this :

```
// get an instance of the graph Module
var graphModule = require("org/arangodb/general-graph");
// load your graph 
var graph = graphModule._graph("yourGraphName");
// get an array of edges between v1 and v2
graph._getConnectingEdges(v1, v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In ArangoDB v.3, you can retrieve all the edges (in Edge collections e1, ... eN) between two vertices V1 and V2 as follows:

```
FOR v, e IN 1..1 ANY V1 e1 ... eN
  FILTER v == V2
  RETURN e
```

If you just want a count, rather than computing the array as above, it would be more efficient to replace the last line above by:

```
  COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO c
  RETURN c
```

#### Addition of V2

> After addition of V2 again

Taken literally, this does not seem to make any sense in ArangoDB. Maybe you meant addition of another edge?